# Setting Input tag to specific Javascript Variable without typing

Tags: javascript, html

I want input to be filled with some variable's value without typing anything into it.I don't want input button to be changed but its content. Let's say I have variable `var text = "Some_text"` and I want it to be shown within input content (not changing `value="send"` to be variable "text"). How can I do it?

```
<form method="POST" name="vform">
  <label for="item">Movie_title: </label><input type="text" name="movie">
  <input id="myInput" type="Submit" value="send">Submit item</input>
</form>
```

Comment: you can't do this.

Answer (score 0):

In your line: `<input id="myInput" type="Submit" value="send">Submit item</input>`  add an attribute placeholder and assign it some text. Like this : `<input id="myInput" type="Submit"placeholder="some text" value="send">Submit item</input>`